# Grails taglib for bootstrap

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, taglib

Can anyone recommend a good taglib for bootstrap to grails? The taglib should consist of the basic components of bootstrap.

I have searched through GitHub and Grails plugins. And haven't succeeded to found a taglib with "standard" bootstrap components

Comment: I'm not sure but I think 're probably looking for something that does not exist. But if you are trying a way to type a little less bootstrap components you can use some plugins for example for sublime has some nice snippet to create bootstsrap components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the [Twitter bootstrap plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/twitter-bootstrap) which fixes the pagination for `<g:paginate>`, there isn't one.

Comment: Sad :( Almost the same conclusion i came to.

Comment: Not really. Twitter Bootstrap is all CSS based and a tag library is more about structure. Making a tag library that allows for the same level of flexibility, when it comes to structure, that Twitter Bootstrap offers would be nearly impossible. There are just too many variations in the structure for it to make sense. However, for your own project if you have a structure you want to use, then create your own tag library.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree totally with you :( I know that bootstrap mostly is based on css. But I was specific asking for the bootstrap components like those http://getbootstrap.com/components/
And I was wondering if someone made it already with some generous move :) But it seems not :)

Answer (score 0):

As @joshua-moore states, there isn't a specific BootStrap tag lib and it's maybe not the job of a tag lib in any case. That said, I am overriding existing tags that are used by scaffolding views to include the "form-control" class in the class attributes, which works for my purposes:

```
class BootstrapTagLib extends FormTagLib {

    Closure field = { attrs ->
        attrs = addFormControl(attrs)
        super.field.call(attrs)
    }

    ...

    private Map addFormControl(Map attrs) {
        addClass(attrs, "form-control")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway, but not the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that Grails very 3.2.0M1 is based bootstrap which is almost the answer to my question.